# Access denied to AppRegNew.aspx page in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, java

When I try to open 'https://{site}/_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx', in order to generate an access token to authorize REST API calls to the SharePoint site to retrieve data and manipulate the site data, I get the below message even though I have admin access:

**Sorry, you don't have access.**

So, Are there any other ways to generate access token other than the steps mentioned [here](https://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/).

Or Is there any extra permission needed to get access to this page? or do we have to change any settings to get this access?

Comment: Are you a site collection admin?

Comment: Thank you, Trevor Seward. I was not a site collection admin before. The page is now accessible.

Comment: @TrevorSeward It worked fine with my Sharepoint site after adding the user as a Site Collection administrator. However, with my company SharePoint site, I don't see an option to add a user as a site collection administrator. I don't see an Admin icon in the top left under the Apps section. Instead, I have a Partner icon which is not accessible. Do we need any license or something to work with SharePoint REST APIs or do you have any idea on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a super old question, but I did have the same problem and eventually got it to work.  In SP Central Administration, look at Application Management -> Site Collection Administrators.  It allows you to designate two individual user accounts (one Primary, one Secondary) as Site Collection Administrators.  You may need to be logged in to Central Administration as one of these accounts already to view / change this setting, I'm not sure.  (I can't imagine why it's done this way instead of role-based with AD groups, but I guess That's Sharepoint For Ya.)